# Установить размеры окна без блокирования изменений для пользователя

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Как установить размер виджета в фиксированные значения, но не запрещать пользователю изменять размеры окна после этого?

`setFixedWidth(42)` устанавливает ширину в нужное значение, но после этого пользователь не может изменять её.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тогда это не фиксированные значения, это просто длина и ширина окна. В классе QWidget нет отдельных методов для установки длины и ширины, но есть метод [QWidget::setGeometry](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setGeometry-1). Можно задать размеры так:

```
QRect geometry(myWidget->geometry().topLeft(), QSize(42, 43));
myWidget->setGeometry(geometry);
```